# Call SignalR hub methods on server side

Tags: c#, server-side, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have followed this tutorial (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/) to get a basic chat app built and working.

I now need to update the clients from the server.  In other words, I need to be able to call the hub methods server side.  I have found several examples using older versions of SignalR / .NET, but none of them want to play nicely with ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Please can someone help me out with a pointer (or an example) on how to send messages from the server.  I think the specific bit I am missing is how to get a reference to the active hub from the server side code, so that I can call its methods.

It feels like it should be simple, so I am probably missing something obvious.

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 5):

Hub methods are meant for the client to call.

On the server, you inject `IHubContext<ChatHub>` and access its `Clients` or `Groups` properties:

```
// Not hub method
public async Task Send(string message)
{
    await _chatHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but *how* do you inject?  This is the elusive part.

Comment: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)